# Fastest way to compute vector in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following (using Python's pandas):

y: n by 1 dataframe

x: n by k dataframe

theta: k by 1 dataframe

Each of the elements in the above dataframes contains a real number.

I need a dataframe w, where w = y'x (' denotes transpose), but w only contains the observations for which y multiplied element-wise by (x * theta) is less than 1. In other words, the dimension of w is at most n by k, and there will be fewer rows if there are some observations that do not meet the criteria.

What's the fastest way (in terms of time) to get w?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to carry out this operation with pandas dataframe, instead of np.matrix?

Comment: Because I loaded it with pandas.read_csv. Actually I wanted to ask, will it be faster with np.matrix or pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes in most cases. I currently can't think of any edge cases in which the answer is no, but there may be one or two. You can either load the input with np.loadtxt then convert np.ndarray to np.matrix, or get the df.values to np.matrix .

Comment: Ok I will start using np matrix from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.values` to access underlying numpy arrays

```
Y = y.values
X = x.values
Th = theta.values

W = Y.T.dot(X)

mask = Y * X.dot(Th) < 1

w = pd.DataFrame(W[mask], y.index[mask])
```